# How to simplify creation of multiple enemies in Pygames?

Tags: python, pygame

See screenshot of the code that I use to make enemies.

[image]

The issue is that when I decided to make a second enemy I created a new class for it:

```py
goblin = enemy(135, 410, 64, 64, 245)
goblin2 = goblin2(350, 260, 64, 64, 500)
```

I need a way to simplify this so that I can create multiple goblins with just one class.

How to do this?

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: Hi, stackoverflow allows for code embedded in the question. Just copy that block of code to the question text box, and while the selected code is highlighted, press ctrl + k.

Comment: you can use one `class` to create many `instances` - you don't need other class with the same code. There is the rule to use uppercase first letter in class's name  - `Enemy` - to easly recognize class in code - `enemy = Enemy(...)`

Comment: next time put code as text, not screenshot. We can't copy code from screenshot and change it and show some solution.

Answer (score 1):

save all your goblins in a list

```
goblins = []
# creating 10 goblins
for i in range(10):
    goblins[i] = enemy(135, 410, 64, 64, 245)

# to access goblin use goblin[0], goblin[1], ... etc...
```